# Trying to query optimize a join based on four fields with IN joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
      RTPropertyUniqueIdentifier
      ,[FA Unique Listing Identifier - Ref ID]
      ,MLS.[Listing Tracking ID]
      , MLS.[Assessor's Parcel Identification Number] as MLS_PARCELID
      , PP.ParcelID
      , GEOID
      , CASE 
        WHEN PP.PP_ParcelID = MLS.MLS_PARCELID then 'PARCEL MATCH'
        Else 'ADDRESS MATCH' END as MATCHTYPE
      ,[Update Timestamp]
          INTO PROPERTY.DBO.PP_MLS_Bridge
  FROM STAGE.DBO.STAGE_MLS_BRG MLS
  join STAGE.DBO.STAGE_PP_BRG PP on 
    (
        PP.PP_ParcelID = MLS.MLS_PARCELID
    ) OR (
        lower(MLS.StreetNum) = lower(PP.AddNum)
        and (lower(PP.AddStreet) like '%'+lower(MLS.Street_Name)+'%' or lower(MLS.Street_Name) like CONCAT('%', lower(PP.AddStreet), '%'))
        and (lower(PP.AddUnitNum) like '%' + lower(MLS.Unit) + '%' or lower(MLS.Unit) like CONCAT('%', lower(PP.AddUnitNum), '%'))
        and lower(PP.AddCity) = lower(MLS.[Property City])
        and lower(PP.AddState) = lower(MLS.[Property State])
        and lower(PP.AddZip) = lower(MLS.[Property Zip])
);
```

The MLS table is 50 Million Records strong.  The PP table is 185 Million Records strong.  This query will run for over 8 days straight, which means I'm not sure I have it optimized as well.  I'm looking for a way to speed it up.

Thanks

Update 1: Execution Plan:
[image]

UPDATE 2: Updated SQL Statement

```
INSERT PROPERTY.DBO.PP_MLS_Bridge
SELECT 
      RTPropertyUniqueIdentifier
      ,[FA Unique Listing Identifier - Ref ID]
      ,MLS.[Listing Tracking ID]
      , MLS.[Assessor's Parcel Identification Number] as MLS_PARCELID
      , PP.ParcelID
      , GEOID
      , CASE 
        WHEN PP.PP_ParcelID = MLS.MLS_PARCELID then 'PARCEL MATCH'
        Else 'ADDRESS MATCH' END as MATCHTYPE
      ,[Update Timestamp]
  FROM STAGE.DBO.STAGE_MLS_BRG MLS
  join STAGE.DBO.STAGE_PP_BRG PP on PP.PP_ParcelID = MLS.MLS_PARCELID
UNION
SELECT 
      RTPropertyUniqueIdentifier
      ,[FA Unique Listing Identifier - Ref ID]
      ,MLS.[Listing Tracking ID]
      , MLS.[Assessor's Parcel Identification Number] as MLS_PARCELID
      , PP.ParcelID
      , GEOID
      , CASE 
        WHEN PP.PP_ParcelID = MLS.MLS_PARCELID then 'PARCEL MATCH'
        Else 'ADDRESS MATCH' END as MATCHTYPE
      ,[Update Timestamp]
  FROM STAGE.DBO.STAGE_MLS_BRG MLS
  join STAGE.DBO.STAGE_PP_BRG PP on
        MLS.StreetNum = PP.AddNum
        and (PP.AddStreet like '%'+MLS.Street_Name+'%' or MLS.Street_Name like CONCAT('%', PP.AddStreet, '%'))
        and (PP.AddUnitNum like '%' + MLS.Unit + '%' or MLS.Unit like CONCAT('%', PP.AddUnitNum, '%'))
        and PP.AddCity = MLS.[Property City]
        and PP.AddState = MLS.[Property State]
        and PP.AddZip = MLS.[Property Zip];
```

Execution Plan:
Part 1
[image]

Part 2
[image]

Comment: read execution plan.

Comment: add execution plan

Comment: You are using `lower` which will inhibit the use of indexes

Comment: explain plan added.  Thanks.

Comment: also the OR and the LIKEs (used that way) are bad in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have 2 terrible table scans. So, I can give you common advices:

1. Remove `LOWER`. SQL Server compares strings ignoring cases
2. Add indexes on `PP.PP_ParcelID` and `MLS.MLS_PARCELID`
3. Replace `OR` in your join with 2 selects with `UNION` - query optimizer will select better plan
4. Try to replace all joins on string like `lower(PP.AddZip) = lower(MLS.[Property Zip])` with some join on simple integer keys (like `PP.AddZipId = MLS.PropertyZipId`). Comparing ints is much simplier

Comment: ok. I can't do ID's at this value right now, but I'm working on a next gen design of my warehouse where I include that.  however, for now, I included a version 2.  Can you take a look at that?  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 add indexes on `PP.PP_ParcelID = MLS.MLS_PARCELID`. Also you don't need switch-case for 'PARCEL MATCH' and 'ADDRESS MATCH'

Comment: ok.  I did that.  what else?  the 1% repartition stream went away, and insert is now at 97%